# Loading entity, set relation depth?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

Is it somehow possible to set a loading level for related entities? An example of related entities:

```
Voucher
- has a Product
    - has a ProductGroup
```

A call like this

```
$voucher->getProduct()->getProductGroup(),
```

causes multiple SQL queries by calling getProduct() and getProductGroup(). I know it is possible to load everything with a big join in querybuilder, but I am looking for a kind of configuration how deep the entities should be loaded by join or proxyobjects. I dont know for what I should search in google. :(

Comment: Nope.  QueryBuilder is really the only way to go for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Daniel: With lazy loading, only required data will be loaded, so you shouldn't worry about depth. As you said, you can use `join` in your repository to reduce the number of queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: I am not sure if that really what I need. It is configured in my entity and the behaviour is allways the same, but I need something different. In another case I want to load it with all relations.

Maybe I need only the vouchers name, I want to load without relations.